# Is there a way to preserve debug information for a static library that is purely an aggregate of other static libraries?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, static-libraries, debug-information

I have a project that builds a static library that is purely an aggregate of other static libraries. This is achieved by adding the input libraries to the project as files. However, even if debug information is available for the input libraries, there is none available for the output aggregate library. If debug information is required for the aggregate library when linked into another binary, the project that builds that binary has to be modified to link with the aggregate library's input libraries instead of the aggregate library itself.

Is there a way to make debug information available for aggregate libraries created in this way? Or should the aggregate library be created in a different way (not adding the input libraries to the project as files)?

Comment: I've been affected by this too -- I'd be interested to know if you've got any further with this.